# Cannot generate NSManageObject for objective C after introducing Swift in project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

Since I added swift classes to my objective C project, the "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." options has no effect anymore. It works find apparently with event the message indicating that the existing files will be erases.

But when I check the files, the attribute newly added to the model are not there.

Can anybody help?

What I tried already without any success:
- restarting the mac
- cleaning
- creating new model versions
- generating in swift (then I can see my new attributes - but I've Categories on the objective C version so for those files I cannot switch to Swift)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update: I tried to rename the generated files and then... the new files appears! I found a solution but I let the question open a few days in case someone provides me with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

There no better answer, so I'll close the question by answering it.

Basically XCode seems to have a process generating the NSManagedObject subclasses with the wrong rights for overwriting the existing files. Maybe XCode put a lock on the existing files.

By deleting the files before the generation, everything is working fine (as I wrote in my comment).

So... I close the issue!